# Wonderware Failed to deploy Access Denied, Invalid Credentials

Tags: deployment, ide, wonderware

After updating Wonderware update 2 to update 3 ,i am facing following error.
Error: Failed to deploy <Platform_Name>: Access Denied, Invalid Credentials

Answer (score 2):

Issue is fix by enabling "everyone permissions" for anonymous users. To enable these permissions, go to: Local Security Policy > Local Policies > Security Options > Network Access: Let everyone permissions apply to anonymous.